# How to keep specific query parameters in varnish

Tags: regex, varnish, strip, query-string

My Question is maybe a bit strange. Normally you would like to strip specific query parameters from the url to cache in Varnish. But I want to do the opposite of this. This is required for redirecting with some query parameters (like utm_source, etc.)

I have a set of query parameters which does NOT need to be stripped off, the rest can be stripped off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a while of trial and error I found a way of doing this.

First of all we used this code in **sub vcl_recv** to strip off any marketing query parameters to clean up the URL:

```
# Store original url in temporary header
set req.http.X-Original-Url = req.url;

# Strip all marketing get parameters
if(req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|utm_[a-z]+|mr:[A-z]+)=") {
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|utm_[a-z]+|mr:[A-z]+)=[%.-_A-z0-9]+&?", "");
}
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "(\?&|\?|&)$", "");
```

Next in **sub vcl_fetch** we used this code to reattach the marketing query parameters after a redirect but strip all other query parameters.

```
if (beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 302) {
    set beresp.http.location = beresp.http.location + "?" + regsub(req.http.X-Original-Url, ".*\?(.*)", "\1");
    set beresp.http.location = regsuball(beresp.http.location, "([&|?](?!gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|utm_[a-z]+|mr:[A-z]+)[\w\d]+=([%.-_A-z0-9]+)?)", "");  # Comment or remove this line to keep the original query parameters after redirect
    set beresp.http.location = regsub(beresp.http.location, "(\?&|\?|&)$", "");
    return (hit_for_pass);
}
```

I also made a quick enable/disable variant, so people can enable/disable the stripping of all non-marketing query parameters. See the comment in the **sub vcl_fetch** code

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an update on this using the latest version of Varnish (e.g. `sub vcl_fetch` has been renamed). The following worked for us:

In `vcl_recv`:

```
# Store original url in temporary header
set req.http.X-Original-Url = req.url;

# strip out query string
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", "");
```

In `vcl_backend_response`:

```
# restore URL params after a redirect
if (resp.status == 301 || resp.status == 302) {
  set resp.http.location = resp.http.location + "?" + regsuball(req.http.X-Original-Url, "(^.*(?=\?)|[?&](?!header1|header2)\w+=[^&]*)", "");
  # strip occurrences of `?&` after removing params
  set resp.http.location = regsub(resp.http.location, "(\?&|\?\?)", "?");
  # some more cleanup (empty `?` or `&` at end)
  set resp.http.location = regsub(resp.http.location, "(\?&|\?|&)$", "");
}
```

Where

- `^.*(?=\?)` keeps only the query string "everything that comes after the `?`" (e.g. `?key1=value1&key2=value2`)
- `[?&](?!header1|header2)\w+` matches key names that does not match `header1` or `header2`
- `=[^&]*` matches the `=` char and the `value` upto the next occurence of `&`

The following the `regsubs` are used for cleaning up. Hope that they are self-explaining.